# SQLite not inserting into table in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

I'm using the following code:

```
$db = new SQLite3('test.db');

$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, the_id TEXT UNIQUE, type TEXT)");

$db->exec("INSERT INTO items(the_id) VALUES ('abc')");
$db->exec("UPDATE items SET type = 'One' WHERE the_id = 'abc'");

$final = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items");

print_r($final->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC));
```

However, I keep receiving a `SQLite3::exec(): UNIQUE constraint failed:` for `$db->exec("INSERT INTO items(the_id) VALUES ('abc')");`.

How can I insert new rows into the table?

If the table is empty, the script will run fine and add a new row.

If the table contains **1 record**, it will run without errors but a new row **won't** be added, even when `the_id` is unique.

If the table contains **1 record** and I run it again, it will run **with** the error mentioned above.

How can I add new rows into this table?

**Edit**

Just to confirm, I am adding different `the_id` values and it will only allow for a maximum of 1 in the table for some reason, when the values are unique

Comment: It seems that the row is added so when you run again you get the error. Double check the table. A "UNIQUE constraint failed" error means that there is a row in the table with the same value in the unique column.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a second field which must be unique: "id" that is also the primary key.
Either you force the value at every new insert (and must be unique) or you set it as an auto-increment in the table and it gets generated by the dB in an automatic sequence

I suggest the second one: add an AUTOINCREMENT keyword after the id field in table create statement

Comment: Like this? `$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,the_id TEXT, type TEXT)");`. Still doesn't work unfortunately, only allows for a maximum of 1 record. Also, I think the ID auto increments anyway, without the attribute

Comment: Did you drop the table before re-creating? Your statement has a "if not exists" clause: so it will try to create, but stop if you didn't drop it before. So change wouldn't apply.

Comment: Btw a side comment: if you run the entire script every time it will try to recreate the table at every run. Usually it is a good practice to create the table once and for all and only change later on when needed (even if you put the "if not exists" the dB will try to run the statement wasting time").